# How to restore contacts from Google account?

Tags: contacts, restore

I backed up my contacts to Google account using Gionee S-plus through       "Settings/Advanced settings/Backup & reset/System backup and restore/Backup to Storage"  .
Pls how will i restore my contacts using Gionee M2.

Answer (score 1):

In Gionee M2, go to Settings > Account > Google then put your Google account and password. Now you should see Sync, check contact in the list. Let it sync and go in the Contact app you should have all your contacts back.